# how do i display another website data in django template

Tags: django

```
**urls.py**
urlpatterns = [
path('',views.index,name='index'),
]
**views.py**
def index(request):
    return render(request,"index.html")
```

**template.html**
my template has
1)input box
2)search button
3)bootstrap card
when i enter any url and hit search button, the website data should appear in the card

```
<input type="text" value="">
<button type="button">Search</button>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">

        <h5 class="card-title">Search results will appear here</h5>
       
      </div>
      </div>
     </div>

     </div>
```

Comment: Just use  HTML iframe

Comment: i am trying get external website data into my template like any website when user enters ,that website data i wanted to display in my page    ,tried like this,it is not showing data                                        
     <iframe class="searchdata" src="https://www.google.com" frameborder="0"></iframe>

Comment: I think this requires the *other website* to provides an `embedded` or `API` for that

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that because of `CORS` and `X-Frame headers` sent by other sites. One way of doing that is to use modules like requests library on the server-side and render its response to your site after processing.

**Tip:** From my experience you can show some websites in an iframe if your domain is on HTTP instead of HTTPS.

Comment: How do I use requests library in template and show data

Comment: You have to use the python 'requests' module in your views. As is I understood you are trying to search data on other websites and show it to yours. Then the best way is to use AJAX for making UI cool and let the server-side taking the load.

Comment: s=requests.Session() 
        s.headers['Content-Type']  ="text/html"   
        res=s.get("https://www.google.com")
        c=res.content
        response = HttpResponse()
        response['content_type'] = 'text/html'
        result={'search':c}
        return render(request,"index.html",result)

Comment: using like this,now getting webpage output,but getting html code of the page printed,but not actual visible elements

Comment: Here are 2 points. The 1st is, you have to filter out what you want from this page using 'requests-html' module i.e we called web scraping. The 2nd point is... Don't waste your time on it,  when google notice huge requests from your server's  ip.. You will get blocked automatically within few minutes. By the way "requests" and "requests-html" are 2 different libraries. For web scraping we use "request-html"